# Apache2 ip problem

Tags: apache2

I have installed apache2 on my local machine (ubuntu 14.04). I am able to see this screen ("It Works!" Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page) by using 127.0.0.1 but not using my network IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: By "my network IP" do you mean the IP address of an interface on the local machine, or your router's public IP address?

Comment: Router's public IP

Comment: are you using a different port than :80 ?

Comment: The port is 80.

Comment: Most home-user grade routers will not perform [hairpin routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning).  If you want to test your apache server on your public IP, ensure that you have port forwarding properly configured on the router, then test it from _outside_ your home network.  A phone will work, if it does not use wifi when inside your house.

Comment: I have the following output for http://canyouseeme.org/  Error: I could not see your service on ...PublicIP on port (80)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reach your `apache` service from external networks, you need to set NAT parameters (port forwarding) of your router, because the router got the public IP address, not your local machine.

So, set NAT/port-mapping of your router as following:

`public-ip:80` ---> `local ip:80`